# what does NASware do?

Tags: hard-drive, nas

Some Western Digital hard drives advertise themselves as having NASWare. My question is.. . what does NASWare do?

When I Google it I get articles talking about what NAS is (network attached storage, I already know that) but not what advantages NASWare-HDD's offer over non-NASWare HDD's.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NASware is exclusive to Western Digital's NAS drives. NASware is a unique firmware that makes the drive deliver more performance in a small NAS setup. It optimizes power use resulting in significant power savings and lower hard drive operating temperatures, which improves the overall reliability and performance of the drive. It also has intelligent error recovery controls, which prevents hard drives from being dropped off the RAID due to extended error recovery. This provides more availability and less down time rebuilding the RAID.

It also minimizes data loss or corruption if an unexpected power loss occurs, by completing the command in process before shutting down.

Comment: Source is [here](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Data-Storage/Western-Digital-Red-Hard-Drives-Boast-NASware-Technology-) (verbatim).